# SQL Need to group data by multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to transform data from table1 into table2

**table1**

```
UserId  Date1
1       9/26/2012
2       9/26/2012
1       9/26/2012
1       9/26/2012
2       9/26/2012
2       9/27/2012
2       9/27/2012
1       9/27/2012
```

**table2**

```
UserId  Date1       recCount
1       9/26/2012  3
2       9/26/2012  2
1       9/27/2012  2
2       9/27/2012  1
```

This obviously does not work, but not sure where to go from here:

```
SELECT 
    UserId,
    Date1,
    Count(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY UserId, Date1
```

Comment: That doesn't work?  What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: are there times on your Date1 column?

Comment: Please explain what "does not work" means and why that should be obvious. For the given data the query you have seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: <bangsHeadOnDesk>It does work, I had a where in my statement that was killing the query and not pulling any records</bangsHeadOnDesk>

Comment: And why exactly was there a need to post that? I submitted an answer as saying the original post answered the question but it will not let me accept it for 2 days.  Please enlighten me.

Comment: You should probably just remove the question altogether

Comment: How? I tried to delete and it said I couldn't because there were answers...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The original post answers the question I asked.  I had a where statement in my query that did not belong there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're displaying just the dates from columns that contain times.  You can use CAST AS DATE from SQL Server 2008 onwards to remove the time portion.

```
SELECT 
    UserId,
    CAST(Date1 as date) Date1,
    Count(*) RecCount
FROM table1
GROUP BY UserId, CAST(Date1 as date)
```

If by `transforming into` you mean putting the data into another table, then

```
INSERT table2
SELECT 
    UserId,
    CAST(Date1 as date),
    Count(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY UserId, CAST(Date1 as date)
```